# An alternative for genetive case with of in scientific writing

Tags: science, scientific-language

I am writing a scientific paper and have a following dillema between two sentences:

> Therefore, it is reasonable to analyze the effect of the mutual
>   coupling in the proposed application.

vs.

> Therefore, it is reasonable to analyze the effect the mutual
>   coupling has in the proposed application.

The first option is clearly more formal and default option. However, is the second option acceptable in scientific literature?

Comment: Does the coupling occur in the application or does the analysis occur in the application?

Comment: The coupling occurs in the application.

Comment: Why do you think the second is informal? To have an effect is perfectly standard English, and in my opinion — based on publishing and refereeing dozens of scientific papers, clearer. You shouldn’t accept answers that just express a subjective opinion without any external justification

Comment: @David: It's not just the choice of the verb **have** but the use of a subordinate clause: **the effect *the coupling has*** instead of a prepositional phrase.  What is that verb "clearer" than?  Your statement is itself unclear.

Comment: It’s subjective. The use of a verb “has” seems to me to produce a separation between cause and effect, aiding comprehension. But style wasn’t the question. The question was about informality. I can see no word, expression or construction that is in any way informal. Active verbs are good

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think the version with **has** is a tad informal.

I'd suggest as an alternative to "has" the verb "occurs":

> Therefore, it is reasonable to analyze the effect of the mutual coupling that occurs in the proposed application.

or

> Therefore, it is reasonable to analyze the mutual coupling that occurs in the proposed application in order to study its effects.

Comment: You “think” but I think different. How is anybody to decide who is correct. Answers on SE EL &U should be supported by external evidence of some sort. Expression of subjective opinion has no place even in comments.

Comment: @David:  Why not leave an answer yourself?  We'll see how you think.